# Android: two Aplication class instances for the same app when doing initialization

Tags: android, initialization

We put all initialization of Android Application in `MyApplication.onCreate()`. And we expected to be executed only once while app loads into memory.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG,"onCreate -----------------------------------------");
        init();
    }
```

However during testing I discovered that Application `onCreate()` is called twice. (Second time likely from a service that I don't know well) Although [documentation says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

> **public void onCreate ()** Added in API level 1
>
> Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service,
>   or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.

Is it be because Application is created for both Activity and Service and the same time?

What I may be missing?

Comment: are you calling `super.onCreate()` ??

Comment: try using `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` on `AndroidManifest`

Comment: You shouldn't be having two androidapplication classes, if needed then you should handle the content through a shared intent for the same application class

Comment: sure `super.onCreate()` is called.  
`"singleInstance" is for Activity, not Application http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Comment: There is only one Android Application class declared in manifest `<application> section`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity and service are probably running in different processes (check `android:process` attribute of both activity and service in manifest file).

Android creates one `Application` context instance per app process.